# my menu overflows the space

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu

I have tried to make a menu that collapses earlier expanded chioces but i cant make it work.

```
var currentId;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(":range").rangeinput({
        progress: true
    });

    /* Slide Toogle */
    $("ul.expmenu li > div.header").click(function () {
        var arrow = $(this).find("span.arrow");

        if (arrow.hasClass("up")) {
            arrow.removeClass("up");
            arrow.addClass("down");
        } else if (arrow.hasClass("down")) {
            arrow.removeClass("down");
            arrow.addClass("up");
        }

        $('#' + currentId).parent().find("ul.menu").slideToggle();
        $(this).parent().find("ul.menu").slideToggle();
        currentId = $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

You can find the homepage at this adress: http://admin.dq.se/kramers/nyamenyer.html

So if I press "BIL" i want "BIL" to expand .. and afterwards if i press "MC" i want BIL to collapse and MC to expand. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Would you explain more specifically what is wrong besides "I can't make it work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slide up everything before sliding down

```
$("ul.expmenu li > div.header").click(function () {

 $(this).parent().siblings().find('ul.menu').slideUp();
 $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.arrow').removeClass('up').addClass('down');

....

});
```

Comment: The only issue with this is if the user clicks the arrow of an already-expanded menu, the menu will slide up and down right away. It's a little awkward UX-wise.

Comment: And it creates a lot of extra function invocations.

Comment: yeah i can see the arrow problem there =)

Comment: Add this after slide up      $(this).parent().siblings().find('span.arrow').removeClass('up').addClass('down');

Comment: @Anton - yeah this will work. My only personal quibble is that it will attempt the slideUp every time a header is clicked. If it's already up, then it's an extra cycle. Not a huge waste, but still it isn't needed. I added a solution where the slideUp is in the if statement, which avoids that.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite right:

```
$(this).parent().find("ul.menu").slideToggle();
```

You need to go up higher:

```
$(this).closest('ul.expmenu').find("ul.menu").slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something roughly like this:

```
    /* Slide Toogle */
    $("ul.expmenu li > div.header").click(function () {
    var arrow = $(this).find("span.arrow");

    if (arrow.hasClass("up")) {
        arrow.removeClass("up");
        arrow.addClass("down");
    } else if (arrow.hasClass("down")) {
        $('.arrow.up.').parents('li').children('ul.menu').slideUp();
        $('.arrow.up.').removeClass('up').addClass('down');
        arrow.removeClass("down");
        arrow.addClass("up");
    }
```

Which basically looks for any 'up' arrows, and brings their menus up (note the DOM traversing), only in the event that the arrow in question is still "down".